# Error installing Sensenet 7.2 from NuGet

Tags: nuget, sensenet

I'm trying to install `Sensenet 7.2` from `NuGet`, however I'm getting the following error while installing the `Sensenet.Services.Install` package.

Error:

> Could not install package 'SenseNet.Common 7.2.0'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I'm using VS 2017, project template is "ASP.NET Web Application".

How to deal with that issue?

Comment: Please check the .Net version of the web project, it should be at least 4.6.1 (the error message says there is a 4.5.1 project in your environment). This requirement is new in this version, previous versions worked in a .Net 4.5.1 project.

Comment: The cause is that we started to convert our projects to .net standard, which is supported by .net framework 4.6.1, so all projects have to be at least on 4.6.1 to be able to work with sensenet packages from now on.

Comment: Thank you, @MiklósTóth. Changing the target to 4.6.1 gives me the same error, only the text changed a bit to reflect changed .Net version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues here.

#### Visual Studio and NuGet version

Updating to the latest (currently VS2017) should solve the package install problem. Previous VS and NuGet versions cannot handle netstandard packages I guess.

#### .Net runtime version

There was a [type forwarding issue](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/300) in .Net Framework 4.6.1 that breaks interop with a netstandard assembly if it contains certain methods in a class marked as Serialized. This means that although your projects may be on 4.6.1, on the target (executing) machine at least **.Net Framework 4.7.2** has to be installed.

For details please visit this [kick-off post](https://community.sensenet.com/blog/2018/07/09/netstandard-first) about moving sensenet to netstandard.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out, that using latest version of VS 2017 does not have that issue. I'm using older version of VS 2017 on my SharePoint development machine (Windows Server 2012) and VS cannot be upgraded because of VS installer requirements.

Comment: Might be an old nuget.exe version (installed with the older version of VS) that does not recognize the netstandard contents of the package.

Comment: However a new issue appears. Running the ".\SnAdmin install-services" command gives me the following error: System.Exception: ReflectionTypeLoadException: Could not load types. Affected types: Lucene.Net.Store.RAMDirectory, Lucene.Net.Search.FieldDoc, Lucene.Net.Search.NumericRangeQuery, Lucene.Net.Search.SortField, Lucene.Net.Index.Term, First message: Type 'Lucene.Net.Store.RAMDirectory' in assembly 'Lucene.Net, Version=2.9.4.301, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' has method 'OnDeserialized' with an incorrect signature for the serialization attribute that it is decorated with.

Comment: Installing .Net 4.7.2 should solve the type load exception, they fixed it in that version of the framework, see the other answer below.